# Not Getting proper number traingle in python

Tags: python

i would like to print a some triangle of numbers. please have look at below code. Can anybody tell me where it's going wrong in following code??

```
x=0
while x<10:
    y=x
    while (y >= 0):
         print y,
         y=y-1
    print x
    x=x+1
```

output:

```
0 0
1 0 1
2 1 0 2
3 2 1 0 3
4 3 2 1 0 4
5 4 3 2 1 0 5
6 5 4 3 2 1 0 6
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 7
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 8
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9
```

required o/p:

```
0 
1 0 
2 1 0 
3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
5 4 3 2 1 0 
6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Change your `print x` statement to `print`.

Comment: `print("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, range(i, -1, -1))) for i in range(10)))` (3.5.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting an extra number at the end of each line because you're printing `x` when you don't need to. I assume you have that print statement there so you can force a line break between different rows of results. If all you want is to move the cursor down a line, you can use `print` with no arguments.

```
x=0
while x<10:
    y=x
    while (y >= 0):
        print y,
        y=y-1
    print
    x=x+1
```

Comment: You beat me by 2 seconds. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `print x` to `print`.  That will output a newline without printing the value of `x`, which is where the unwanted numbers come from:

```
x=0
while x<10:
    y=x
    while (y >= 0):
         print y,
         y=y-1
    print
    x=x+1
```

The output is:

```
0
1 0
2 1 0
3 2 1 0
4 3 2 1 0
5 4 3 2 1 0
6 5 4 3 2 1 0
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```